# Two cases of a switch with similar blocs of code

Tags: java

Is it possible to merge these two cases into one so I don't have what is basically duplicated code except for the cast part?

```
       case ScheduleActionsMediator.ACTION_CREATE_RENDITION:
            final List<CrewMemberVO> crewMembers = new ArrayList<CrewMemberVO>();
            CrewMemberRenditionActionStruct struct = (CrewMemberRenditionActionStruct) action;
            for (final CrewMemberVO crew : struct.getAffectedCrews().values())
                if (crew != null)
                    crewMembers.add(crew);
            this.cacheFacade.deleteCrewMembers(crewMembers, false, this.crewMemberRules);
            break;
        case ScheduleActionsMediator.ACTION_CREATE:
            final List<CrewMemberVO> crewMembersTwo = new ArrayList<CrewMemberVO>();
            CrewMemberCreateModifyActionStruct structTwo = (CrewMemberCreateModifyActionStruct) action;
            for (final CrewMemberVO crew : structTwo.getAffectedCrews().values())
                if (crew != null)
                    crewMembersTwo.add(crew);
            this.cacheFacade.deleteCrewMembers(crewMembersTwo, false, this.crewMemberRules);
            break;
```

Comment: More context, please! What is this code supposed to do? What is the `switch` statement? Are these the only two cases?

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    case ScheduleActionsMediator.ACTION_CREATE_RENDITION:
    case ScheduleActionsMediator.ACTION_CREATE:
        List<CrewMemberVO> crewMembers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final CrewMemberVO crew : action.getAffectedCrews().values()) {
            if (crew != null) {
                crewMembers.add(crew);
            }
        }
        cacheFacade.deleteCrewMembers(crewMembers, false, crewMemberRules);
        break;
```

If `action`'s type supports the `getAffectedCrews` method, this will work as stands.  This gets rid of the duplicate code, which will make it easier to maintain.

Of course, we don't have sufficient context here to see if `action` supports the `getAffectedCrews` method without casting.  If it doesn't, you'd have to make changes outside of this snippet in order to make things work.  It's unclear how extensive those changes might be.  If you post a followup question, consider posting at least the entire method.  We'd need the type for `action` and how it relates to the two cast types.  Also include the `ScheduleActionsMediator` definition.

I removed the `this.` from several variables.  Unless there is a conflict, you don't need it.  Of course, some people prefer to use it to indicate which are object fields rather than local variables.

I removed the `final` from `crewMembers`, as not telling us much.  It doesn't keep a mutable type like `ArrayList` from being modified.  It only keeps which object is represented from being changed.

The `final` on `crew` is more useful, but not by much.

In newer versions of Java, you don't need to specify `<CrewMemberVO>` the second time.  You can just say `<>`.  Not only does that save you some typing now, but it helps simplify future maintenance.

Comment: All the 'final' and 'this' are configured in Eclipse's save actions as per our project manager preferences and what you did was my first try, but `action.getAffectedCrews()` requires the cast. I edited my answer to show what I ended up doing.

Comment: I mean, I answered my own question with what I did, if you could provide feedback I would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can make the common part as a function, then call it with different parameter from different branches.

Answer (score 0):

After talking to some more people we've reached the conclusion that we could create an interface and have CrewMemberRenditionActionStruct and CrewMemberCreateModifyActionStruct implement it and the method getAffectedCrews, but that would be overkill.

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
        case ScheduleActionsMediator.ACTION_CREATE_RENDITION:
            this.deleteCrewMembersFromCache(((CrewMemberRenditionActionStruct) action).getAffectedCrews().values());
            break;
        case ScheduleActionsMediator.ACTION_CREATE:
            this.deleteCrewMembersFromCache(((CrewMemberCreateModifyActionStruct) action).getAffectedCrews().values());
            break;
```

And here's the private method:

```
  private void deleteCrewMembersFromCache(final Collection<CrewMemberVO> values) throws WplexError
    {
    final List<CrewMemberVO> crewMembers = new ArrayList<CrewMemberVO>();
    for (final CrewMemberVO crew : values)
        if (crew != null)
            crewMembers.add(crew);
    this.cacheFacade.deleteCrewMembers(crewMembers, false, this.crewMemberRules);
    }
```